# sequential criterion

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

This is one of the practice questions I'm working on:

Use the Sequential Criterion to prove that $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ is not
uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

I need some help to get started, for instance, what sequences should I be choosing?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{\pi(2n+1/2)}$ and $y_n = \sqrt{\pi(2n-1/2)}$.

What happens to the function along these sequences?

What can you say about $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n-y_n)$?